# How to execute an autohotkey script when launching a specific application

Tags: windows, fullscreen, autohotkey, titlebar

I have successfully used to following autohotkey script to achieve what I want (remove title bar and window frame from a windowed game):

```
;-Caption
LWIN & LButton::
WinSet, Style, -0xC00000, A
return
;

;+Caption
LWIN & RButton::
WinSet, Style, +0xC00000, A
return
;
```

What I want is for "WinSet, Style, -0xC00000, A" to be executed automatically when a specific application is launched.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply make an AHK launcher for the game and use it instead of the shortcut icon or taskbar icon or whatever else you're using to launch the game.

```
Run, d:\somepath\game.exe
WinWait Game window title goes here
WinSet, Style, -0xC00000
ExitApp
```

Answer (score 2):

Altough wOxxOm's answer is perfectly acceptable. You can also do this in a persistent  script by using Settimer and WinExist .

```
#persistent 

SetTimer, isItRunning, 1000

isItRunning: 
if winexist("yourprogram")
     WinSet, Style, -0xC00000

Return
```

Comment: `winwait` in an infinite loop would be better for two reasons: [almost] instant reaction and no needless running of code (not too taxing though in case of AHK).